# How to get the value of a method in the run area that was changed inside of method?

Tags: java, variables

I apologize if the title is confusing. I'm very new to Java coding and have just completed a coding course provided through my High School.

I am trying to create a small text-adventure game using Java through a program called codehs. In the game there is a player, with a class for their stats. There are also monsters in the game, which have a separate class based on their individual stats. Each monster is created at random per encounter and is spawned from a pool of monsters that scale with player level.

My problem arises when I initiate a fight between the player and the monster. I currently initiate the fight through a method called monster fight, where the method inputs the players level and their health in a variable called HP (kept separate from the stats class). The problem is, after the fight, my player has obviously lost some HP with the fight, but since the HP variable is changed inside of the method, it reverts back to the default full HP after the fight when I try to display the current HP. Is there a way I can display the HP of the player after the fight in the run area?

I apologize for the long wording and probably terrible understanding of Java, but I would appreciate any help trying to make this work.

Edit: Here is some code

What I call in the run area:
monsterFight(player.getLevel(), player.getHP());

Method for monster Fight:

public void monsterFight(int level, int HP)
    {

```
    int whatMonster = Randomizer.nextInt(1,3);

    Monster monster = null;

    if(whatMonster == 1)
    {
    monster = new Monster("Gremlin", level, 1500);
    }

    if(whatMonster == 2)
    {
    monster = new Monster("Troll", level, 3000);
    }

    if(whatMonster == 3)
    {
    monster = new Monster("Brute", level, 4000);
    }

    Monster.getHP();
    System.out.println(monster);


    int enemHP = Monster.getHP();
    while (HP > 0 && enemHP > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        String fbfAttack = readLine("How will you attack? Choose lightning or fireball: ");

        if (fbfAttack.equals("lightning"))
        {
            System.out.println("Your lightning blasts the ");
            int damage = Randomizer.nextInt(400,500);
            enemHP = enemHP - damage;
        }

        if (fbfAttack.equals("fireball"))
        {
            System.out.println("Your fire burns the " + monster.getName());
            int damage = Randomizer.nextInt(700,1000);
            enemHP = enemHP - damage;
        }

        if (enemHP <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("The " + monster.getName() + " is at: " + enemHP + "HP");
        int enemAttack = Randomizer.nextInt(200,300);
        HP = HP - enemAttack;
        System.out.println("The " + monster.getName() + " attacks! Your HP: " + (HP));
        }
        if (HP < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Game over, you died");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("HP in fight method " + HP);
        newHP(HP);

}

public int newHP(int HP)
{
    return HP;
}
```

}

Comment: Absolutely there is a way :) show us your code for the monster fight and we will tell you where you're going wrong. Also, welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: You might get more help if you share a bit of code. You could return the new health points after the fight and use that value to update the player.

Comment: please give us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. First of all, let me just say there are plenty of ways to solve this. Here's one:

you could pass in a `player` object to the `monsterFight(Player player)`

```
public class Player {

   private int health;
   private int lvl;

   public Player(int health, int lvl) {
       this.health = health;
       this.lvl = lvl;    
   }

  ...
  // getters & setters

}
```

and then in the `monsterFight(Player player)` you could call `player.setHealth(health)` whenever the player loses health!

Comment: That's awesome, good luck with your game! looks a lot of fun :) @Brian

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you should have an object which is initialised in the main or which has its state saved somewhere global and after each fight you change the HP of the player to the new value on that object. To show the HP you just query the objects state.

```
Player p;
object Player {
   int level;
   int health;
}

public int getLevel(){
   return this.level
}

public int setLevel(int level){
   this.level = level
}

public int getHealth(){
   return this.health
}

public int setHealth(int health){
   this.health = health
}
```